# Assign the returned value of a tkinter func to a lambda variable

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I want to inform user if they clicked in a specific section of root window.

```
import tkinter as tk
# Setting up the window
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

''' If the user clicked in a specific
    section of root window, then
    the terminal will inform user '''
RightOnPoint = lambda event,x,x0,y,y0: print("You clicket right on point!") if x-x0>132 and x-x0<300 and y-y0>15 and y-y0<36 else None
root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event,root.winfo_pointerx(),root.winfo_rootx(),root.winfo_pointery(),root.winfo_rooty(): RightOnPoint)

# Mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

using bind to associate mouse left-click. And to get absolute mouse coordinate I use something like this:

```
root.winfo_pointerx()-root.winfo_rootx()
```

where `root.winfo_pointerx()` is represented by x
and the value of `root.winfo_rootx()` is assigned to x0 and so on.

and I'm getting an "Invalid syntax Error", although I cannot understand what I have done wrong.

I tried to define a function instead of using a lambda function like such:

```
def RightOnPoint():
    x=root.winfo_pointerx()
    x0=root.winfo_rootx()
    y=root.winfo_pointery()
    y0=root.winfo_rooty()
    if x-x0>132 and x-x0<300 and y-y0>15 and y-y0<36:
        print("You clicket right on point!")
    else:
        pass
root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: RightOnPoint())
```

Comment: Don’t use `lambda` here. A function will make the solution easier to see. The `lambda` here only serves to make the code more difficult to write and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RightOnPont()` function expects one positional argument. That argument is `event information`. So do it as the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
# Setting up the window
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

''' If the user clicked in a specific
    section of root window, then
    the terminal will inform user '''
def RightOnPoint(event):
    x=root.winfo_pointerx()
    x0=root.winfo_rootx()
    y=root.winfo_pointery()
    y0=root.winfo_rooty()
    if x-x0>132 and x-x0<300 and y-y0>15 and y-y0<36:
        print("You clicket right on point!")
    else:
        pass
root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: RightOnPoint)
# RightOnPoint = lambda event,x,x0,y,y0: print("You clicket right on point!") if x-x0>132 and x-x0<300 and y-y0>15 and y-y0<36 else None
root.bind("<Button-1>",RightOnPoint)

# Mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Mujtablue your function throws an error: `TypeError: RightOnPoint() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.  `RightOnPoint()` has to accept one argument

Answer (score 0):

My second try was correct, I only calculated the wrong section of root window.
This works:

```
import tkinter as tk
# Setting up the window
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

''' If the user clicked in a specific
    section of root window, then
    the terminal will inform user '''
def RightOnPoint():
    x=root.winfo_pointerx()
    x0=root.winfo_rootx()
    y=root.winfo_pointery()
    y0=root.winfo_rooty()
    if x-x0>132 and x-x0<300 and y-y0>15 and y-y0<36:
        print("You clicket right on point!")
    else:
        print((x-x0,y-y0))
root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: RightOnPoint())

# Mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for not trying myself and asking a question immediately after problem occurred.